# extends ChannelHandlerAdapter, but does not override or implement a method from ChannelHandlerAdapter

Tags: java, oop, annotations, overriding, netty

What does this method from [EchoClientHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.java) override?

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(firstMessage);
}
```

compile error:

```
-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/NettyEcho/build/empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/NettyEcho/build/generated-sources/ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/NettyEcho/build/classes
    [javac] /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/NettyEcho/src/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.java:27: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
```

code from github:

```
package io.netty.example.echo;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;

/**
* Handler implementation for the echo client. It initiates the ping-pong
* traffic between the echo client and server by sending the first message to
* the server.
*/
public class EchoClientHandler extends ChannelHandlerAdapter {

    private final ByteBuf firstMessage;

    /**
* Creates a client-side handler.
*/
    public EchoClientHandler() {
        firstMessage = Unpooled.buffer(EchoClient.SIZE);
        for (int i = 0; i < firstMessage.capacity(); i ++) {
            firstMessage.writeByte((byte) i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(firstMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ctx.write(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
       ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        // Close the connection when an exception is raised.
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

When I look at [ChannelHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerAdapter.html), I don't see these methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up versions.

In Netty 4, you have for [`EchoClientHandler`](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.html):

```
public class  EchoClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter
```

And in Netty 4, [`ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html) has a `channelActive` method.

Your link is for [`EchoClientHandler`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.java) in Netty 5, for which [`ChannelHandlerAdapter`](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerAdapter.html) has been updated and has a lot more methods, including `channelActive`.

Comment: frustrating.  so, the sample code for EchoClientHandler is for Netty 5?  Netty 4 is recomended...  How do I know which sample code is for Netty 4?

Comment: Your links are from the current version being developped. To get the 4.0 API, you go on http://netty.io/wiki/index.html and click on the version 4.0 API reference link or source code link.

Comment: does the sample at https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/echo/EchoClientHandler.java  use netty 4 or 5?

Comment: This is Netty 5 since it the version currently being developed

Comment: Use netty 4 branch for examples that fit netty 4. As stated above master is netty 5